# Как отрендерить задачу только в нужной категории-компоненте?

Tags: reactjs

Есть два стейта:

```
const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([]);
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

И код:

```
<ul className={styles.list}>
  {toDoList.map(({ categoryName, color, id }) => (
    <CategoryContainer
      title={categoryName}
      titleColor={color}
      key={id}
      openCreateTaskForm={openCreateTaskForm}
      isCreateTaskFormOpen={isCreateTaskFormOpen}
      createTask={createTask}
      cancelCreateTask={cancelCreateTask}
      openCategoryNameForm={openCategoryNameForm}
      isCategoryNameFormOpen={isCategoryNameFormOpen}
      onSaveEditCategoryName={onSaveEditCategoryName}
      onCancelEditCategoryName={onCancelEditCategoryName}
      tasks={tasks}
    >

    {
    tasks.map(({task, id, isDone}) => (
      <Task key={id} id={id}>{task}</Task>
    ))
    }

    </CategoryContainer>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Проблема:
При добавлении задачи в одну категорию, сама задача появляется во всех категориях. Как сделать так чтобы задача добавлялась только в категорию где она была создана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании таски не плохо было бы указывать id категории в которой она создавалась, а затем просто сравнивать при переборе условие вроде idCategory===id && <Task ...>

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю суть вашей мысли, но не понимаю как это реализовать.

Таска создается этой функцией:

В компоненте формы новой таски

```
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSaveCreateTask({
      task:inputValue,
      isDone: false,
      id: uuid(),
    });
  }
```

Стейт тасков обновляется так:

```
function createTask(inputValue) {
    setTasks((prevState) => [...prevState, inputValue]);
  }
```

Непонятные моменты:

1. Каким образом я могу определить категорию в которой была создана таска?
2. Если определяю категорию в которой была создана задача, то в объект задачи надо добавить id категории?

Comment: "в объект задачи надо добавить id категории" если вам нужен подобный функционал то без этого не обойтись

Comment: Я понимаю...и согласен с вами. но как определить id категории? т.е. у меня может быть много категорий и у всех разные id. Как определить категорию в которую была добавлена задача?

Comment: у тебя есть компонент категории так? внутри него есть кнопка добавления таски которая вызывает функцию создания таски, передавай в неё вместе с текстом и idCategory и сохраняй в объект. В объекте категории добавь id и передавай его внутрь компонента категории